# Temporarily disable jQuery event handler while function is running

Tags: jquery, events, handler, jquery-jscrollpane

**Context** I have a navbar that triggers the scrollTo function on my main content container to scroll to the appropriate section. I use **jscrollpane** plugin to have a pure javascript scrollbar on this container. It give me access to a custom event "jsp-scroll-y" that listens on mouse scroll event to  the give position in the container.

I also have some animations on my navbar that colors the navbar tab when its section is being displayed.
**Problem:** I would like to implement a scroll spy so that when the scrollbar is within a certain range,which tells me which section is displayed, I want to animate the proper navbar tab. However, I do not want this animation to work when the scrolling occurs by clicking one of the navbar tab because if I scroll to the last element starting from the first one, it will animate each element in between since the scrollspy will detect that we passed through each of the sections.

**My solution that does not work:** I put code and pseudo code that I think is relevant, but I can provide full code if requested.

**Possible explanation:** From a bit of investigation, it seems like the problem arise from the fact the the scrollTo method is animated and therefore takes some time to complete, but the code continues to progress and reattaches the scroll-spy event before the animation is actually complete. I think this means I have to find a way to way for the scrollTo animation to complete and after that I can reattach the event handler.

```
     function navbarclickEvent(navbarElement, navbarId){

      //detach scrollspy from jspPane, reattach after scrollTo to prevent switching through           all sections.
      scrollbar.off('jsp-scroll-y');

      // navbar animation logic

      //scrolling to sections

      scrollbar.on('jsp-scroll-y');
      return false;
   }

function scrollspy(event, scrollPositionY, isAtTop, isAtBottom){
    //logic to animate proper navbar tab depending on section displayed
}
scrollbar.bind('jsp-scroll-y',scrollspy); // in main code.
```

Comment: Why not define a global variable and set it to false. Then, use an if-conditional within the event handler and if value = true, then do not execute the code, but if false, then execute the code. At the end of the execution, set the boolean variable back to false.

Example:
`var isActive = false;

function eventHandler()
{
    if (isActive)
      return;
    else {
      isActive = true;
      doThis();
    }

    isActive = false;
}`

Answer (score 1):

If you know which function you want to disable, you can use [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/).

Re-using your code :

```
function navbarclickEvent(navbarElement, navbarId){
  scrollbar.unbind('jsp-scroll-y', scrollspy);

  // navbar animation logic
  //scrolling to sections

  scrollbar.bind('jsp-scroll-y', scrollspy);
  return false;
}

function scrollspy(event, scrollPositionY, isAtTop, isAtBottom){
  //logic to animate proper navbar tab depending on section displayed
}

scrollbar.bind('jsp-scroll-y', scrollspy); // in main code.
```

Comment: How is bind/unbind going to work differently than on/off ? It seems like bind/unbind has been deprecated as of jquery 1.7

Comment: Yes, it is recommended to use on/off rather than bind/unbind. The difference is that on/off have an additional & optional argument to select sub-elements permanently, even if they don't exist at the time on/off is called. Very convenient if you built some parts of your DOM at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess was right. My problem was a race condition where the scrolling event would finish after we reactivate the scrollspy, which means it never being really off. I solved the issue using the power of jscrollPane API by extending the default animate method and adding a call back on the complete event. This way, by setting a global variable to false and reactivating it via the complete callback, I make sure my scrollspy won't fire when i use my navbar to scroll, but will when I use the mouse or keyboard.

```
// global 
isScrollSpyEnabled = true;
var customAnimate = function (ele, prop, value, stepCallback) {

      var params = {};

      params[prop] = value;

      ele.animate(

         params,

         {

            'duration'  : Config.scrollSettings.animateDuration,

            'easing' : Config.scrollSettings.animateEase,

            'queue'     : false,

            'step'      : stepCallback,

            'complete'  : toggleScrollSpy

         }

      );

   }

 function toggleScrollSpy(){

      isScrollSpyEnabled = !isScrollSpyEnabled;

      console.log('isScrollSpyEnabled',isScrollSpyEnabled);

   }
```

in the main

```
 scrollbar.bind('jsp-scroll-y',scrollspy);

  api = scrollbar.data('jsp');

  api.animate = customAnimate;
```